# npm run build get npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I'm learning angular with webpack and I got stuck on a webpack episode. Whenever I try to run `npm run build` command on my CMD I get this error:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 2
>   npm ERR! open-house@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the open-house@1.0.0 build script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional >

After searching for various solutions on the web I end up here in hope you guys can help me. Here is the *webpack.config.js*:

```js
module.exports = function (options) {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

    /**
     * Developer tool to enhance debugging
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/build-performance#sourcemaps
     */
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    /**
     * Options affecting the output of the compilation.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    output: {

        /**
         * The output directory as absolute path (required).
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
         */
        path: helpers.root(pathBuild),

        /**
         * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
         * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
         */
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',

        /**
         * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
         * They are inside the output.path directory.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
         */
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',

        /** The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
         * inside the output.path directory.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
         */
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'

    },

    plugins: [

      /**
       * Plugin: DefinePlugin
       * Description: Define free variables.
       * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
       *
       * Environment helpers
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
       */
      // NOTE: when adding more properties, make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
      new DefinePlugin({
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
          'process.env': {
              'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
              'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
              'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
          }
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: NamedModulesPlugin (experimental)
       * Description: Uses file names as module name.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/a04ffb928365b19feb75087c63f13cadfc08e1eb
       */
      // new NamedModulesPlugin(),

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true,
        options: {
          context: helpers.root('src'),
          output: {
              path: helpers.root(pathBuild)
          },

          /**
           * Static analysis linter for TypeScript advanced options configuration
           * Description: An extensible linter for the TypeScript language.
           *
           * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
           */
          tslint: {
            emitErrors: false,
            failOnHint: false,
            resourcePath: 'src'
          }
        }
      })
    ],

    /**
     * Webpack Development Server configuration
     * Description: The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server.
     * The server emits information about the compilation state to the client,
     * which reacts to those events.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
     */
    // devServer: {
        // port: METADATA.port,
        // host: METADATA.host,
        // historyApiFallback: true,
        // watchOptions: {
            // aggregateTimeout: 300,
            // poll: 1000
        // },
        // outputPath: helpers.root(pathBuild)
    // },

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
        global: true,
        crypto: 'empty',
        process: true,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    }
});};
```

And file *package.json*:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress",
    "test": "karma start",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "rebuild-sass": "npm rebuild node-sass"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.2",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
    "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
    "angulartics2": "^2.0.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "bootstrap-loader": "2.0.0-beta.19",
    "chart.js": "1.1.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-animation": "0.1.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "2.0.1",
    "fullcalendar": "3.6.2",
    "google-maps": "3.2.1",
    "http-server": "0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "jquery-touch-events": "1.0.7",
    "leaflet": "0.7.7",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
    "ng2-responsive": "^0.6.9",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^2.0.4",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-pipes": "^1.5.7",
    "ngx-uploader": "2.2.5",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "postcss-load-config": "1.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "primeng": "5.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.3",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5",
    "webpack-sources": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "2.7.40",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
    "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.61",
    "@types/node": "7.0.12",
    "@types/source-map": "0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "2.2.14",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.2",
    "tslib": "1.6.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typedoc": "0.5.10",
    "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
    "parse5": "^2.2.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.2.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "css-loader": "0.28.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.10",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.1.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try running `npm run build:dev`

Comment: I want to resolved this for prod. :D

Comment: Is that working fine for dev? Try clearing your npm cache. using `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Hi @GopalSharma, it gets error in bold dev and prod. :(.
I have tried: npm cache clean --force, npm install, npm run build
But it still fail

Comment: Could you please share the Repo link from where you have created this project?

Comment: sorry @GopalSharma, this project is private. I can only provide file config and package.json. Which file you want more ?

Comment: Try updating your `webpack-dev-server` from  `2.4.2` to `2.9.7`  install using `npm install webpack-dev-server@2.9.7 --save-dev`

Comment: I think node version missed? Try to downgrade it.